# Accessing to OUT parameter (t_cursor type) from stored procedure using go and InstantClient

Tags: database, oracle, go, cursor

I'm dealing with an Oracle DB, connecting from go via InstantClient (version 11) (https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8). I need to be able to load this object and browse results... t_cursor output parameter.

I have tried many strategies, I know how to map function parameters to go structures but I don't know how to work with t_cursor type since it seems not being implemented in InstantClient

Example of stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure EXAMPLE(a IN NUMBER, b IN NUMBER, c OUT T_CURSOR) AS BEGIN
```

[Edit] We have also tried to execute SQL blocks from code to try to handle this third parameter.

i.e.

If you add something like

```
declare
  c t_cursor;
begin
  EXAMPLE(:1, :2, c)
end
```

then I don't know how you can get the block to return a result set that contains the cursor.

```
declare
  c t_cursor;
begin
  EXAMPLE(:1, :2, c)
  select 1, c from dual
end
```

The whole block returning the result of that select would be ideal but oracle blocks do not return result sets afaik.

Anyone who can bear a hand on this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Looks like the support [is there](https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8/pull/383). Did you dig that?

Comment: Thank you @kostix but that patch applies only to cursor returned in aresultset but the stored procedure of this question does not return any rows... it only has an OUT parameter and this patch does not seem to be able to handle it

Comment: Is it possible to script SQL around calling this SP then? I mean turn it into a query which declares a vadiable, executes the SP and then runs `SELECT` on the returned cursor?

Comment: That is another possible strategy but already tried to do  and it seems almost impossible to get the result. I just extended the original question with that. Thank you very much.

Comment: FWIW, the godror driver has an example `TestCallWithObject()` at https://github.com/godror/godror/blob/v0.20.0/z_plsql_types_test.go#L812

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the driver https://github.com/rana/ora instead.

> *Rset may be passed to Stmt.Exe when prepared with a stored procedure accepting an OUT SYS_REFCURSOR

The README.me even has that exact example.

Caveats:

1. It's unclear whether the database/sql interface may be used or you are limited to the lib specific API.
2. Instant Client gets restricted to versions from 12.1.0.1.0 on.

Comment: The rana driver is dead - its final maintainer went on to create and maintain the [godror driver](https://github.com/godror/godror).